# Facebook JS SDK - restoring FB session

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a site which allows users to link their "native" accounts with their FB accounts - this is accomplished by using FB JS API which plants FB cookie in the browser, which cookie is then parsed by my code etc.

Now, when user logs out of the site (FB session is then closed with `FB.logout();` call) and logs in again using his credentials (and not using FB Connect), I would like to restore FB session automatically (without showing FB popup), if possible, to allow posting comments to FB wall.

I'm aware that I could post comments from the backend, using OAuth access_token I have, but I'd like to do it with JS SDK. With the backend version things are relatively simple, but I cannot wrap my head around client-side solution - e.g. how to handle situation in which some other user is logged into FB, and the FB session of returning user of my site clashes with the existing FB session of that other user.

Can anyone advise me something on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than instigating a Facebook session each time the user logs in, you could change your extended permissions scope to include offline_access. This would give you an access token that is long lived and allows you to perform authorised requests on behalf of the user at any time.

It will only require them to authorise your application once, which presumably will be when the "link" their account.

There is some information on extended permissions here for you to reference:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: Yes, meanwhile I've found this `offline_access` permission, but thanks anyway. I've also realized that JS SDK is more or less tied to FB session in the browser, so it might be that I'm trying to win a lost war and I should better spend my time on the backed :-)

Comment: I do find the PHP SDK is a little more geared up for this type of access. Best of luck!